# Julia: Self-referential and recursive types

Tags: data-structures, struct, julia, self-reference

What I am trying to do is not very straight forward, maybe it is easier if I start with the result and then explain how I am trying to get there.

I have a struct with two fields:

```
struct data{T}
    point::T
    mat::Array
end
```

What I would like to do is nest this and make the field mat self-referential to get something like this:

```
data{data{Int64}}(data{Int64}(1, [1]), [1])
```

The 'outer' type should not store [1] but reference to the innermost mat. I am not sure if this makes sense or is even possible. The field mat should store the same large array repeatedly.

I have tried something like this (n is the number of nested types.

```
struct data{T}
    point::T
    g::Array
    function D(f, g, n)
        for i = 1:n
            (x = new{T}(f, g); x.f = x)
        end
    end
end
```

Again I am not sure if I understand self-referential constructors enough, or if this is possible. Any help/clarification would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "The 'outer' type should not store [1] but reference to the innermost mat." I suppose that there's only one `mat` in the data and there's no references to the mat, right?

Comment: @JunTian that's right!

Answer (score 4):

The exact pattern will depend on what you want to achieve but here is one example:

```
struct Data{V, A <: AbstractArray{V}, T} 
    mat::A
    point::T

    Data(mat::A, point::T = nothing) where {V, A <: AbstractArray{V}, T} =
        new{V,A,T}(mat,point)
end
```

Usage

```
julia> d0 = Data([1,2,3])
Data{Int64,Array{Int64,1},Nothing}([1, 2, 3], nothing)

julia> d1 = Data([1.0,2.0],d0)
Data{Float64,Array{Float64,1},Data{Int64,Array{Int64,1},Nothing}}([1.0, 2.0], Data{Int64,Array{Int64,1},Nothing}([1, 2, 3], nothing))
```

Tips:

1. Never use untyped containers. Hence, when you want to store an `Array` you need to have its type in your `struct` defintion.
2. Use names starting with a capital letter for `struct`s
3. Provide constructors to have your API readable

Last but not least. If you want to have several nesting levels for such structure the compiling times will hugely increase. In that case it would be usually better to use homogenous types. In such scenarios you could use perhaps type `Union`s instead (unions of small number of types are fast in Julia).

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description, the `data` seems like a very general wrapper. Maybe you can try something like this:

```
mutable struct Wrap{T}
    w::Wrap{T}
    d::T
    function Wrap(d::T) where T
        w = new{T}()
        w.d = d
        w
    end
end

function Wrap(d, n::Int)
    res = Wrap(d)
    cur = res
    for _ in 1:n-1
        cur.w = Wrap(d)
        cur = cur.w
    end
    res
end

Wrap([1], 4)
# Wrap{Array{Int64,1}}(Wrap{Array{Int64,1}}(Wrap{Array{Int64,1}}(Wrap{Array{Int64,1}}(#undef, [1]), [1]), [1]), [1])
```

Comment: I would define here `w` as `w::Union{Wrap{T}, Nothing}`. Otherwise it remains in an `#undef` state for the root element which is kind of ugly.

Comment: Thanks this is close to what I was looking for, tho the type for say Wrap([1], 2) should be: Wrap{Wrap{Int64}}(Wrap{Int64}(1, [1]), [1])